# Is it valid to change lpstrFile on CDN_FILEOK via Hook on GetOpenFileName/GetSaveFileName?

Tags: winapi

Is it valid to change the contents of `lpstrFile` on `CDN_FILEOK` via Hook on `GetOpenFileName()`/`GetSaveFileName()`?

The reason is that I may need to append additional information to the file name for `GetSaveFileName()`.  The user could enter a generic name like "my file" and the program handles adding information user wouldn't know to add (already part of filter).  Then it would check for overwrite and put up a question if okay to overwrite.   If not, I can just use the custom data field, but I couldn't find any reference if it's allowed to change the contents of `lpstrFile`

TIA!!

Comment: `I may need to append additional information`: Isn't that what [`OPENFILENAME.lCustData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/commdlg/ns-commdlg-tagofna) is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on your definition of valid. The designers of this API did not intend for you to do this but if it works, it works™. These dialogs will probably not change their internal design ever again since Microsoft have a fair amount of application compatibility to worry about in this area and these dialogs were replaced by the COM based API in Vista+.

My recommendation would be to store the address of your buffer in `lCustData` as well before calling the Open/Save function and only modify that buffer. The dialog could in theory use its own buffer in some places and there might not be space for you to write anything in those and there is no way to figure out their size.

In practice, there seems to be no problem to play with the buffer behind Windows' back. In the past I have even replaced the actual buffer address with a new bigger memory block when implementing support for multi-file-select.